# Printing values of an array using a function in C language

Tags: arrays, c, function

I am pretty new to programming and I was working on printing arrays using functions and I ran to the following error.

```
Test.c: In function ‘main’:

Test.c:21:54: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘theta’
21 |  printf("The theta values are = %lf\n", x[i], theta(x[i]));
   |                                                     ~^~~
   |                                                      |
   |                                                      double
Test.c:5:21: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
5 | double theta(double x[N])
  |              ~~~~~~~^~~~
```

And here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 50

double theta(double x[N]);

int main(){
    int i;   
    double x[i];

    printf("The theta values are = %lf\n", x[i], theta(x[i]));
    return 0;
}

double theta(double x[N]){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        x[i] = (double)(i)/ ((double)(N) - 1.0);
    }
    return x[i];
}
```

I just want to print 50 values between 0 and 1. Just like `linspace(0:1:50)` in MATLAB.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `int i; double x[i];` - *undefined behavior* . `i` has no formal value at this point, and thus `x` has no reasonable capacity. Once fixed, `theta(x[i])` should be `theta(x)`, but then you have another problem: `return x[i];` in `theta` will breach your declared dimension of `x` if you indeed declare it as `double x[50]` in `main`.

Comment: You need to initialise i as in the discrete number of elements you want in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 50

double* theta(double x[], int nb_elements){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < nb_elements; i++){
        x[i] = (double)(i)/ ((double)(nb_elements) - 1.0);
    }
    return &x[0];
}

int main(){
    int i;   
    double x[N];

    theta(x, N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%lf\n", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in declare function, you cannot set size of array.
change to

```
double theta(double* X)
```

Second, do double theta(double x[N]); in main function.

and this is compiler didn`t advise you but I found bug in your code.

First, i in theta is different with i in main

Second, use `for` to print

I think you want this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 50

double* theta()
{
  int i;
  double x[N];
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
  x[i] = (double)(i)/ ((double)(N) - 1.0);
 }
 return x;
}


int main(){
 int i;   
 double* x=theta();
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("The theta values are = %lf\n", x[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

And I like this code more

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 50

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%lf\n",i/(N-1.0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```